# SQL filling sparse data with previous non-null records

Tags: sql, null, missing-data

I have a database table with some missing records and I need to fill with the most recent non-null record by dimension. I'm trying to use LAST_VALUE but can't seem to get it to work:

```
SELECT MAX(Date), ID, LAST_VALUE(Value IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date)
FROM TABLE_1
```

[image: source table and desired output]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Explain what you mean by "can't seem to get it to work".

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table 
where (id, date) in ( select id, max(date) from table group by id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, you can use `row_number()` to get the most recent row:

```
select date, id, value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

There may be other methods as well, depending on your database.

I'm rather baffled by your description and code.  They seem to have nothing to do with the transformation you want.

Comment: I was definitely trying to oversimplify from a more complicated task - that sad, I'll give row_number a try